# Camera Movement on Sphere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a camera for my player object which is a sphere. It is suppose to rotate the camera and the player. But when I move my player it moves like crazy because it is a sphere. I do not know how to solve the issue. I am not sure if it is due to the rotation.

Nothing.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraC0ntroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float RotationSpeed = 1;
    public Transform Target, Player;
    float mouseX, mouseY;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        CamControl();   
    }

    void CamControl()
    {
        mouseX += Input.GetAxis("MouseX") * RotationSpeed;
        mouseY -= Input.GetAxis("MouseY") * RotationSpeed;
        mouseY = Mathf.Clamp(mouseY, -35, 60);

        transform.LookAt(Target);

        Target.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(mouseY, mouseX, 0);
        Player.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, mouseX, 0);



    }
}
```

I expect it not to start flying around.

Comment: Is the camera a child of the sphere?

Comment: No it is not but I have put the player in a gameobject slot in the camera.